# big O notation of this code

Tags: c, big-o

```
int ara(int dizi[], int ilk, int son, int deger) { 
      int indeks;    
      if ( ilk > son ) 
        return 0; 

      indeks = (ilk + son) / 2; 
      if ( dizi[indeks] < deger ) 
        return ara(dizi, indeks+1, son, deger); 
       else if ( dizi[indeks] > deger ) 
        return ara(dizi, ilk, indeks-1, deger); 
       else  
       return 1; 
} 

for (i=1; i<2*n; i++)   { 
    printf("Bir sayi giriniz: "); 
    scanf("%d", &sayi); 
    sonuc = ara(matrix, 0, n-1, sayi); 
    if ( sonuc == 1 ) 
      printf("Found!\n"); 
     else 
      printf("Not Found!\n");  
}
```

what can be the big-O notation of this code? my guess is N*(2^(logN))

I have assigned my hw already! this is just my pre-curiosity!

Comment: You can simplify your answer further(I'm not sure whether it's correct or not). Assuming log is base 2, 2^(log N) = N, so your answer would be O(N^2).

Comment: Your guess is wrong. :-)

Comment: Why is this closed as not a real question?  There is a question here, with a definite answer (not the one the questioner thought), given by ephemient.

Comment: Of course it's a real question, just an easy one.

Comment: @Mike: O(2^log n) = O(n) in any base.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Not quite.  2^log_b(n) == 2^(log_2(n)/log_2(b)) == (2^log_2(n))^(1/log_2(b)) == n^(1/log_2(b))

Comment: Should not I accept ephimient's answer as correct?

Comment: I believe that my answer is correct.  What we are quibbling about in the comments here is how your (incorrect) guess could be simplified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ara` is a recursive implementation of binary search.  That is O(log n).

It is called 2n-1 times.  Multiplying the two terms, the program as a whole is O(n log n).

Comment: You beat me to it by seconds!

Answer (score 0):

Looks linear to me. But your formatting is pretty screwed up, so it's hard to tell.

EDIT: Alright, recursion involved. Not linear, then. It would be easier if we had meaningful variable names.

Comment: Just because you don't speak Turkish doesn't make the variable name non-meaningful :-)

Comment: thanks paxdiablo! the vars are vars you know (x,y,z, bla. bla.).I am new here and I cannot insert int main() method into text area as code. so I omitted.